# Better way to cache in node js

Tags: node.js, database, redis, memcached

I have been reading through some instructions on using redis and memcache. Can someone input on which would be more suitable?

Our scenario, here is to cache results from a database query and store it for a period of time, if the same value is called it should be used from the cache if its within the time interval.

Can someone share an example of how this can be achieved . just a simple example would do it?

Comment: you have 2 separate questions here, 1. redis vs memcache, which is too broad. 2. example of how to implement this, which I would ask, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Both Redis and Memcache should work for your use case. But Redis has more features compared to Memcache. Redis can provide persistence of cached data, Memcahe doesn't have persistence. Redis can provide high availability as well as clustering. Memcache doesn't have clusering and HA (some libraries impose HA, clustering from client side, but that is less reliable). Redis provides more data structures and features. Overall, Redis is a better choice as it is kind of Memcache++++.